# How do i generate random numbers in loop then store it in a file every 1000000 numbers?

Tags: c

So basically, in an infinite loop, i have to generate random numbers. I then have to create files in iteration where in 1st loop it's file1.txt, 2nd loop it's file2.txt and so on. We use the files to store every 1000000 random numbers generated, so file1.txt stores the 1st 1 million numbers, file2.txt stores the next 1 million and so on. But i think i messed up with the code. Can you help me?

```
int rng(){
    int i;
    FILE *fptr;
    int k = 0;

    char buffer[32];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(char) * 32, "file%i.txt", k);
    fptr=fopen(buffer, "wb");
    for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "%d", (rand() * rand()) % 1000001);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: Choose a language, either C or C++.

Comment: There is no infinite loop in this code. Every time `rnd()` is called, it starts over at `file0.txt`. And there are no delimiters being written to file between the numbers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you tell me how to make it infinite?

Comment: @odella place another loop around the one you have already: `for(;;) { snprintf(); for(i) { } fclose(); k++; }`

Comment: @odella Variant: Place this loop around the call to `rng`; to get individual indices then, though, you'd need to make `k` static or pass it in as parameter.

Comment: Why do you think you "messed up"? What is not working as expected? What have you tried to spot the error?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not working as i expected. i think what is wrong in here is i failed to understand the logic. I mean, i know how it should be working but i can't write down as code. I'm sorry if i confuse you

Comment: If this programm really runs (virtually) endlessly, at some point in time, the int will overflow. However, as it is signed: undefined behaviour - at least for now; C++20 seems now to base signed data types on 2's complement, maybe they dropped the UB part as well; but if, you'd get files with negative name indices, which likely is not in your sense either...

Comment: @Aconcagua first of all, i wanna say thank you. I am really, really, new in this field. This is my school task and i need to pass this one. And i have to be frank, i don't understand any of these comments. Can you please help me? Can you please fix what's wrong in my code? Thank you

Comment: @odella First comment: you have a loop that prints out 1mio values into a file - and then terminates. And then? You need to restart the whole matter. Most simple fix: Restart via calling rng itself within a loop. However, then you'd initialise `k` to 0 within each call, resulting in repeatedly overwriting one and the same file again and again. Have you learned the concept of static variables within functions already? This would be one approach to solve the issue, as the variable is initialised once and continues to exist over various function calls, retaining the value assigned latestly.

Comment: @odella The other variant: `int k = 0; for(;;) { rng(k++); }` and making `k` a parameter instead of local variable (or you try the variant in given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349276/1312382)).

Comment: @odella: Imagine `int` only had three bits. Then you'd start at 0 (0b000), 1 (0b001), ... 3 (0b011) - and now? Adding 1 results in (0b100), but that's already the negative value with largest absolute value (here: -4)! This is called overflow (the number you try to calculate does not fit into the data type any more). According to the standard (as for now), this is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) for signed types (not for unsigned; changing with C++20, though).

Comment: @odella To fix (either UB or getting negative values), use `unsigned int k`, in case of overflow, you'd restart with 0 then.

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you so much for giving me your time, to explain it. thank you so much, it's really helpful

Comment: @odella You're welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can make an endless loop using `while(1)` and then use a simple counter to count the number of elements in the current file.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ELEMENTS_PER_FILE 5

int main(void) {
    unsigned k = 0;
    unsigned file_number = 1;

    printf("Open file%u.txt\n", file_number);

    while(1)
    {
        if (k == ELEMENTS_PER_FILE)
        {
            ++file_number;
            printf("Open file%u.txt\n", file_number);
            k = 0;
        }

        ++k;
        printf("   Add random number #%u to file\n", k);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Open file1.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
   Add random number #3 to file
   Add random number #4 to file
   Add random number #5 to file
Open file2.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
   Add random number #3 to file
   Add random number #4 to file
   Add random number #5 to file
Open file3.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
. . .
```

All you need to do is to replace the `printf` with the code doing what the print says.

Using a function to generate a single file, you can organize the code a little better. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ELEMENTS_PER_FILE 5
#define FILES_TO_GENERATE 3

void make_file(unsigned num)
{
    int i;
    printf("Open file%u.txt\n", num);
    for (i=1; i <= ELEMENTS_PER_FILE; ++i)
    {
        printf("   Add random number #%d to file\n", i);
    }
    printf("Close file%u.txt\n", num);
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned file_number = 1;

    while(file_number <= FILES_TO_GENERATE)  // or while(1) if you really want infinite
    {
        make_file(file_number);
        ++file_number;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Open file1.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
   Add random number #3 to file
   Add random number #4 to file
   Add random number #5 to file
Close file1.txt
Open file2.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
   Add random number #3 to file
   Add random number #4 to file
   Add random number #5 to file
Close file2.txt
Open file3.txt
   Add random number #1 to file
   Add random number #2 to file
   Add random number #3 to file
   Add random number #4 to file
   Add random number #5 to file
Close file3.txt
```